# regular expression to extract a link tag from an html string on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have an HTML page source which is in string format on the server-side

I need to extract a  from the string and add it to an array.There can be multiple links with the same starting tag. i need to push the extracted string to an array

the `<link rel="icons"................ >` can contain anything inside the tag.I have mentioned the startTag and endTag in the code below.

```
  var startTag = '<link rel="icons"';
  var endTag = '>';
  const re = new RegExp('(' + startTag + ')(.|\n)+?(' + endTag + ')', 'g');
```

However, When i console the value of re, it is not the one I expect.

DesiredOutput

```
['<link rel="icons" href="icons1.png"','<link rel="icons" href="icons2.png"',<link rel="icons" href="icons3.png"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use Cheerio. Regex are poorly suited for handling HTML.

Comment: [tony the pony he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3670132)

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)+?`, in JS, use `[^]+` or `[\s\S]+` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (the replace is just to remove extra whitespace):

```js
const data = `
  <link 
    rel="icons"
    href="icons1.png"
  >
  <link 
    rel="icons"
    href="icons2.png"
  >
  <link 
    rel="icons"
    href="icons3.png"
  >
`;

const links = data.match(/<link.*?>/gs)
  .map(link => link.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));

console.log(links);
```

If you're in an environment that doesn't support the `s` flag, you could use `/<link[^]*?>/g` instead.

Comment: hi @scott
What if I have to just get the href value from the links in the map for the elements which match the <link rel="icons"..... > condition

For example:["icons1.png","icons2.png",""icons3.png""]

Comment: @eric.joy In that case, you don't need the `map` you could just use this regex: `const links = data.match(/(?<=href=")\w+\.\w+/g);` [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is useful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: If that answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: In this scenario, it works perfectly fine as it only returns an array of links which consists of <link rel="icons" from the page source.

const links = data.match(/<link rel="icons".*?>/gs)
  .map(link => link.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));

I would also like to take out the href from the links which have rel="icons" present and discard any other href(s) which doesn't have the rel="icons" condition